# How to open Play Market via a voice command?

Tags: google-now

How to open Play Market application on Android via a voice command?

Command "open play market" in Google Now just searches the Web. I suspect this is a problem for any application of composite name.

Comment: I have never experienced any problem with composite names, it opens the app right away. With 'Play Market' you mean 'Play Store'? Because that's how it's called now.

Comment: It turns out, "open Play Store" command works fine. In my locale the application is still called Play Market, that has misguided me. Please create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Now has no problem opening apps with composite names. The problem is probably your voice command: the app is no more called Market. The right command is "open Play Store", which is the actual name.